# Symfony2: Doctrine: Base table or view not found: 1146 tablename is same

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity

Today i put my symfony 2.6 project from my local windows machine to my linux webserver

When i go on my site it prompts the login page as expected. Im logging in with the same user credentials how i am logging in locally. I have a users and a role table. After i am logging in successfully the following error prompts:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.name AS name2, t0.color AS color3 FROM employee t0':
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dzqoqnoa_cms.employee' doesn't exist

I had checked google but i found only the lower case problem.

My Entity:

```
namespace WO\OrganizerBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Employee
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="employee")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="WO\OrganizerBundle\Entity\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */.............
```

My Controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$employees = $em->getRepository('WOOrganizerBundle:Employee')->findAll();
```

My Database:

[image: Database structure on server]

i have cleared all caches with the following commands:

```
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
php app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
rm -rf app/cache/
```

Where the hack is the problem??

**EDIT**

Here are my config files:

config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

config_prod.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

Now i rename all from lowercase (employee) to uppercase (Employee) but nothing changed!

Comment: does your repository class exist at `WO\OrganizerBundle\Entity` namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Your linux server is case sensitive so solution is Just Change your table name with

> RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name;

From employee To Employee
e.g 
 RENAME TABLE employee TO Employee. If there are other apply for other also.

Comment: But why i dont need this at the login? table role and users and users_role are lowercase

Comment: I did it but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

My Server provider changed my project directory to another server so i can use php 5.5.2 but ive got no notification about it. So my ssh address changed and the dns not checked in the new ftp address.

Now everything work like expected.